Recyclerview does not update after adding item
I am implementig a chat conversation as a recycler view but I am not succeeding to update the list when I am typing a new message. Here is the adapter class:
class ConversationAdapter(messagesList: List<ChatMessageModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var m_MessagesList: List<ChatMessageModel> = messagesList

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View, context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var m_Sender: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.conversation_sender)
        var m_Message: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.conversation_message)
        var m_Date: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.conversation_timestamp)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.conversationlayout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView, parent.context)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message: ChatMessageModel = m_MessagesList[position]
        val holderView = holder as MyViewHolder
        holderView.m_Sender.text = message.getSender()
        holderView.m_Message.text = message.getMessage()
        holderView.m_Date.text = message.getTimestamp()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return m_MessagesList.size
    }

    fun updateSections(messagesList : List<ChatMessageModel>) {
        m_MessagesList = messagesList
    }
}

Here is the question is the method updateSections correct. I am still a novice in Kotlin, but m_MessagesList is a immutable list. Can I still write like that ?
This is the update function in the conversation fragment:
private fun sendMessage() {
        val message = m_EditText.text.toString()
        var formattedDate = DateTimeUtils.getDateTimeNowAsString()
        val chatMessage = ChatMessage(0, m_MultiplayerRound.getUserId().toInt(), m_MultiplayerRound.getUsername(), m_UserId.toInt(), m_Username,  m_MultiplayerRound.getUserId().toInt(), m_MultiplayerRound.getUsername(), message, Date.from(Instant.now()))
        val chatMessageModel = ChatMessageModel(chatMessage, m_MultiplayerRound.getUsername(), m_MultiplayerRound.getUserId())

        m_MessagesList = m_MessagesList + chatMessageModel
        m_ConversationAdapter.updateSections(m_MessagesList)
        m_ConversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

Again the question about the update of m_MessagesList. Can one write something like that in Kotlin ?  I verified with the debugger and the m_MessagesList variable seems to update correctly. Finally why does the recycler view does not update ?
This is the onCreateView function of the fragment:
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation1, container, false)

        val sendMessageButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.send_message) as Button
        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener {
        sendMessage()
    }
        m_EditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.message_edittext)

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_conversation)
        val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        recyclerView.adapter = m_ConversationAdapter

        return rootView
}

Many thanks!
EDIT
I am adding the following code to describe better my problem:
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        prepareMessagesList()
    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        prepareMessagesList() 
    }

The prepareMessagesList() method reads the current chat messages from the database and displays them in the RecycleView:
private fun prepareMessagesList() {

        m_UserId = requireArguments().getLong("conversation/userid")
        m_Username = requireArguments().getString("conversation/username")!!

        var ownUserId = m_MultiplayerRound.getUserId()
        var ownUsername = m_MultiplayerRound.getUsername()

        var messagesFromDb : List<ChatMessage>? = null
        runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
            launch {
                messagesFromDb = m_DatabaseService.getMessages(ownUsername, ownUserId , m_Username, m_UserId, ownUsername, ownUserId )
            }
        }

        if (messagesFromDb == null)
            return

        m_MessagesList = transformMessagesListToConversationModel(messagesFromDb!!)
        m_ConversationAdapter = ConversationAdapter(m_MessagesList)
        m_ConversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

The method creates the Adapter object for the RecyclerView. If I am calling this method in the onResume() method as well as in the onAttach() method, the list of chat messages are not updated when I am writing a new chat message. If I am calling the method only in the onAttach() method the adding of a new message works.
I am assuming this is related to the recreation of the Adapter in the prepareMessagesList() function. Can anyone please explain this ?
